# With money we will get men, said Cæsar, and with men we will get money

Tags: ancient-rome, quotes, reference, julius-caesar, jefferson

In [Notes on Virginia](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/jefferson-the-works-vol-4-notes-on-virginia-ii-correspondence-1782-1786), Jefferson wrote:

```
With money we will get men, said Cæsar, and with men we will get money.
```

I'm interested in where this was sourced. I don't expect that Jefferson was quoting or even necessarily paraphrasing Caesar, but I'd like to know:

1. Is there a particular historical (or literary) moment this is referencing, or is this only a kind of life-summary?
2. What sources, classical or otherwise, might Jefferson have used in coming to this conclusion?
3. If this was meant to refer to a particular instant in Caesar's life, what classical sources, if any, document what Caesar said at that time?

These questions are, of course, all tangled up together. Answers to any of them would be sufficient.

In trying to answer the second and third parts I have perused the [Thomas Jefferson's Libraries Project](https://tjlibraries.monticello.org/), [The Life of Julius Caesar](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Lives/Caesar*.html), and [The History of Rome](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/baker-the-history-of-rome-vol-1).

Comment: Caesar had to take out an enormous loan when they formed the triumvirate.  That would be my best guess.

Comment: Could the quote be from a non-historic source like Shakespeare? Something that would have been well known to people in the 18th century though I believe his play Julius Caesar relies on actual quotes from antiquity.

Comment: @DamionKeeling I definitely wondered about Shakespeare (that’s why I added “(or literary)” to my question). I haven’t been able to find a source in Julius Caesar or other plays, though.